# SQL Server Data Query on Possible Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

SQL Server 2000

I have a table which lists out the months where a particular product can be sold.

```
ProductCode     MonthNum    MonthName
XXX             1           January
XXX             2           February
YYY             1           January
YYY             3           March
YYY             5           May
ZZZ             6           June
ZZZ             7           July
```

I need to construct a query that would allow me to pass some parameters:

```
ProductCode
LatestMonthNum
LatestYear
FutureForecast
```

that would allow me to construct a set of data list with the total rows based on the number of FutureForecast value and the rows' value would be beyond the passed LatestMonthNum and LatestYear parameter values.

For example, if I pass the following values to the query:

```
ProductCode         YYY
LatestMonthNum      5
LatestYear          2012
FutureForecast      5
```

I would have the data as follows:

```
ProductCode     MonthNum    Year
YYY             1           2013
YYY             3           2013
YYY             5           2013
YYY             1           2014
YYY             3           2014
```

Comment: Apologies if the title is misleading. Not sure how to word this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a table of months and years in the future (something like a numbers table):

```
CREATE TABLE future (month int, year int);
DECLARE @m int;
SET @m = 1;
DECLARE @y int;
SET @y = 2000;
WHILE (@y < 2200) -- will my brain be in a jar by now?
  BEGIN
  WHILE (@m < 13)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO future (month, year) VALUES (@m, @y);
    SET @m += 1;
    END
  SET @m = 1;
  SET @y += 1;
  END;
```

Then you can join your products table with the future!

```
SELECT TOP @FutureForecast
  p.ProductCode, p.MonthNum, f.[year]
FROM Products AS p
JOIN future AS f ON f.[month] = p.MonthNum
WHERE 
  p.ProductCode = @ProductCode
  AND (p.MonthNum > @LatestMonthNum OR f.[year] > @LatestYear)
ORDER BY f.[year], p.MonthNum
```

Comment: This seems sound, but requires a larger than necessary table that has a max limit of the year 2200, which theoretically becomes a maintenance issue for some futuristic developer (you never know how long a system will live, write code expecting it will live forever).

Comment: You are, of course, correct but my great great grandkids will need *something* to do. You could write the query to create a temp table @FutureForecast years long every time it runs. I wasn't sure SQL 2000 had table valued variables.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Select * From 
(SELECT     ProductCode, MonthNum, Year, RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY 
    CAST('1/' + CAST(MonthNum AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(Year AS varchar) 
    AS datetime)) AS 'RANK' 
FROM         dbo.MyTable
WHERE     (ProductCode = @productcode) AND (MonthNum > @monthnum) AND 
(Year > @latestyear)) tbl Where tbl.Rank <= @futureforcast
```

Where is your `year` column?

Comment: The year is the part that is being calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work. You could turn the loop into a CTE (only for SQL 2005+), but I am not sure if that gains you that much in this case.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempOrder
(Order INT IDENTITY (1,1), ProductCode VARCHAR(MAX), MonthNum INT)

INSERT INTO #TempOrder 
SELECT ProductCode, MonthNum
FROM ProductTable
WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode AND MonthNum > @LatestMonthNum
ORDER BY MonthNum DESC

    --Increment the year from the start if it is already over the max stored
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempOrder)
    SET @LatestYear = @LatestYear + 1

INSERT INTO #TempOrder
SELECT ProductCode, MonthNum
FROM ProductTable
WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode AND MonthNum <= @LatestMonthNum
ORDER BY MonthNum DESC

DECLARE @MaxId
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(Id) FROM #TempOrder

CREATE TABLE #ForecastData (ProductCode VARCHAR(MAX), MonthNum INT, Year INT)
DECLARE @CurrentId INT
SET @CurrentId = 1
DECLARE @CurrentCount INT
SET @CurrentCount = 0
WHILE(@CurrentCount < @FutureForeCast)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #ForecastData
    SELECT ProductCode, MonthNum, @LatestYear
    FROM #TempOrder
    WHERE Id = @CurrentId

        --Increment the Id, and if it's over the max in the table 
        --Reset to 1 and increment for a new year
    SET @CurrentId = @CurrentId + 1
    IF @CurrentId > @MaxId
    BEGIN
    SET @CurrentId = 1
    SET @LatestYear = @LatestYear + 1
    END

    SET @CurrentCount = @CurrentCount + 1
END

SELECT #ForecastData
```

(This solution only for SQL 2005+)I am extremely rusty on CTE's but I figured I would give my attempt at this as a CTE also. This replaces everything from above from CREATE TABLE #ForecastData.... down:

```
;
WITH ForecastData (ProductCode, MonthNum, Year)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT ProductCode, MonthNum, @LatestYear AS Year, Id AS LastId 
    FROM #TempOrder
    WHERE Id = 1
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT ProductCode, MonthNum, 
    CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Year + 1 ELSE Year,
    Id AS LastId
    FROM #TempOrder
        JOIN ForecastData
            ON Id = CASE
                      WHEN LastId = @MaxId THEN 1
                      ELSE LastId + 1
                    END
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT *
FROM ForecastData;
GO
```

Comment: He says he has SQL 2000 (*I know!*) which didn't support CTE's ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966090/are-common-table-expressions-cte-available-in-sql-server-2000 )

Comment: You are correct, I missed the SQL 2000 part, I will note that the CTE is only for 2005+. The original answer should work fairly efficiently though.